# What are the difference syscall and int 0x2E instructions?

Tags: windows, x86, kernel-mode, system-call

From this question: [How does the Windows Native API communicate with the kernel?](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/16075/23069)

Here is an example of `ZwClose(HANDLE Handle);` system call in NTDLL.DLL in Windows 10 X86_64:

```
NtClose         proc near
mov     r10, rcx
mov     eax, 0Fh
test    byte ptr ds:7FFE0308h, 1
jnz     short loc_a
syscall
retn

loc_a:
int     2Eh
retn
NtClose         endp
```

My question is, why there is two different instruction `syscall` and `int 0x2E` in one subroutine? The `0xF` value in EAX is the ID of `ZwClose()` and/or `NtCose()`. While debugging, code execution never goes to `int 0x2E`, `syscall` instruction is always executed and [`ds:7FFE0308h` becomes zero](http://www.osronline.com/article.cfm?id=257).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`7FFE0308h` is a pointer inside the `KUSER_SHARED_DATA` struct.

> The pre-set address for access from kernel mode is defined symbolically in WDM.H as KI_USER_SHARED_DATA. It helps when debugging to remember that this is 0xFFDF0000 or 0xFFFFF780`00000000, respectively, in 32-bit and 64-bit Windows. Also defined is a convenient symbol, SharedUserData, which casts this constant address to a KUSER_SHARED_DATA pointer.
>
> The read-only user-mode address for the shared data is 0x7FFE0000, both in 32-bit and 64-bit Windows.

Ref: https://www.geoffchappell.com/studies/windows/km/ntoskrnl/structs/kuser_shared_data.htm

We see from that ref above that SharedUserData+0x308 is

> 0x0308 ULONG SystemCall

for Windows versions 1511 and higher.

So what does it do?

```
//
// On AMD64, this value is initialized to a nonzero value if the system
// operates with an altered view of the system service call mechanism.
//

ULONG SystemCall;
```

from recent ntddk.h

...not very helpful.

So what's the difference between int 2e and syscall **in this context?**

Ref: https://twitter.com/honorary_bot/status/966609444674162688

> Might be a clue: 'int 2e' instruction can be trapped by vmx, syscall not

More info here: https://www.amossys.fr/fr/ressources/blog-technique/windows10-th2-int2e-mystery/

---

**In the context of your question** the `ntdll.dll` `int 0x2e` system calls probably have something to do with Virtualization Based Security. They have been present in Windows 10 since version 1511, after having been removed as a syscall method since Windows 8.

Answer (score 6):

`int 2Eh` is used on 32bit OS to enter the kernel mode. On 64-bit, the same is obtained by using `syscall`. The check done on memory address `0x7ffe0300` is one of [the ways to detect the bitness](http://www.rohitab.com/discuss/topic/40881-a-quick-way-to-detect-64-bit-windows/).